# how do thrift Types integrate with local ORM model Types

Tags: thrift

Do I need to implement a convertor to translate local ORM model objects to thrift objects, and then return to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from most simple cases, in which you could directly map your application specific data types to the thrift IDL types you would need some translation code. And thinking about what you are going to be communicating over the wire instead of just sending your domain objects is a must for any distributed app anyway. Right granularity is one of most important aspects of distributed applications.